# Local Accident Data

Tags: usa, traffic

Is there somewhere I can get detailed information on real-time traffic accidents?

The data I need is accident location (zip code is best) and the names of the people involved.

Comment: Do you need this as USA data or will any country do, if there is geographic information?

Comment: USA. I'll start with any major city but I eventually need to get all of the United States.

Comment: Why do you need the names of the people??

Answer (score 1):

### [US Accidents (3.5 million records)](https://www.kaggle.com/sobhanmoosavi/us-accidents)

#### A Countrywide Traffic Accident Dataset (2016 - 2020)

This dataset has been collected in real-time, using multiple Traffic APIs. Currently, it contains accident data that are collected from February 2016 to June 2020 for the Contiguous United States.

This is a countrywide car accident dataset, which covers 49 states of the USA. The accident data are collected using two APIs that provide streaming traffic incident (or event) data. These APIs broadcast traffic data captured by a variety of entities, such as the US and state departments of transportation, law enforcement agencies, traffic cameras, and traffic sensors within the road-networks. Currently, there are about 3.5 million accident records in this dataset. Check [here](https://smoosavi.org/datasets/us_accidents) to learn more about this dataset.

**Coverage**

The dataset covers 49 states of the US.

More details can be [found here](https://smoosavi.org/datasets/us_accidents)

You can download from [here](https://osu.app.box.com/v/us-accidents-june20) or from Kaggle

Comment: Thanks, it's good accident data but it doesn't have the names of the people involved which is the most important part of this request.

Comment: Why do you need the names of the people??

Comment: It's the requirement I was given